# accessing dictionary in asp.net using jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, dictionary

Hi I declared a dictionary in .cs file of asp.net but I want to access the contents of this dictionary by using a jquery function. The jquery function takes key as input and in the body of the function it should access the dictionary in the .cs of asp.net and process it and jquery should output the value corresponding to the key. Can you suggest a way to do this.

The code which I a writing is

```
public string DictJson { 
   get { 
      MouseOverFieldDict mdict = new MouseOverFieldDict(); 
      JavaScriptSerializer jSer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
      return jSer.Serialize(mdict.FieldDict); 
   } 
}
```

I added above code in .cs file as a property and I tried to access it in the script which I wrote in aspx page

```
var dict = $.parseJSON('<%=DictJSON %>'); 
alert(dict);
```

but I'm getting error 
The name 'DictJSON' does not exist in the current context . The error is showing for DictJSON declared in the script part

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think you need to persist your dictionary into a javascript variable and use it in your js scripts.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do that but I come across serialization using Json but I didn't get that process

Comment: It's good practice to post some code of what you've try, so people can figure out what's the problem and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your casing is incorrect - should be `DictJson`, not `DictJSON`. Inside the code block in your page, the code is C#, so it's case-sensitive.

Additionally, since you're returning a JSON string, you really don't need to put it in quotes and then parse it - in fact, there's a good chance that won't work. You can instead do either:

```
var dict = <%= DictJson %>;
```

or you can do something a little different if you don't want to mix your server and client scripts together:

```
<script type="application/json" id="dict-contents">
    <%= DictJson %>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dict = JSON.parse(jQuery("#dict-contents").html());
</script>
```

Comment: FYI: The reason the `$.parseJSON('<%=DictJSON %>')` wouldn't work is that JSON allows single quotes which are not escaped, so if one of your values had an apostrophe, it would break the string. I think some JSON libraries will escape single-quotes, but my understanding is that technically it's invalid.